# Metal fork creating scorch marks and sparks in microwave oven

Tags: safety

I had a metal fork in a bowl in a microwave oven.  I turned it on, the turning plate rotated, and the end of the fork struck the back wall of the microwave.  There were sparks, and a black arc remained on that wall forever.  How could this happen?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate Electroboom's experiments?? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyTmJX_TC84

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76683/168695

Comment: how could what happen? ... forgetting fork in bowl? ... sparks? ... black arc?

Answer (score 1):

The bowl has capacitance more than air but no electrodes and the 1/4 wavelength of the Klystron microwave is about the radius of the bowl. Since the bowl isn't conductive it is coupled by microwave impedance inversion of  1/4 wave reflections to the forked electrode also near a 1/4 wavelength. now you have a very high power arc from conjugate impedance matching with high voltage arc followed by low voltage high current.

$$Zap. $$

The Air acts as negative incremental resistance.

Don't try alum. foil, as more sparks will fly, but do try a series of marshmallows on wax paper and you can measure the speed of light from the standing waves.

Is wax paper lossy? I haven't tried but expect so. Beeswax is very lossless. I tried to melt a new toilet ring into a new shape and it didn't even warm up.